# natbib: Error with citation having multiple authors `Undefined control sequence. \cite{citationkey}`

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am trying to cite a reference using the [`informs2014` bibliography style](https://pubsonline.informs.org/pb-assets/Management-Science-template-1489419504967.zip), but I keep getting the `Undefined control sequence` error when there is more than one author in a citation. MWE:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{citationkey}

\bibliographystyle{informs2014}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

`references.bib`:

```
@article{citationkey,
  title={Something important},
  author={Big Guy and Another Big Guy},
  journal={Prestigious Journal},
  volume={47},
  number={7},
  pages={966--978},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Institute}
}
```

Errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \cite{citationkey}
Undefined control sequence. ... \protect\BIBand{} Guy(2001)}]{citationkey}
```

What confuses me is that I have been using the bibliography style file for a while without encountering this issue before.

Comment: This could help to find the problem. Replacing `\cite{citationkey}` by `\nocite{*}` produces the error `Undefined control sequence. ...tem[{Guy \protect\BIBand{} Guy(2001)}]{citationkey}`. I think the problem is related to `\BIBand`.

Comment: When we run `bibtex`, edit `bbl` to remove `\protect\BIBand{}`, save it, and compile twice, it works. After running `bibtex` again, the `bbl` will be wrong again.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, I also suspect it is related to `\BIBand{}`; in fact that's how I realized it has to do with multiple authors. But I don't really understand the mechanism behind well.

Comment: I am not sure if the command `\BIBand{}` should be defined on the style or if it is standard from `natbib`.

Comment: If you define it on preamble with `\providecommand{\BIBand}{and}` it works. Of course, you have to know what the style wants to use as `and` separator for authors.

Comment: In the zip file you posted, the sample shows that they use simply `and`.

Comment: @Sigur Ah I think I found it. In the .tex template in the .zip, there is the line `\def\BIBand{and}%`. If you would like to put it into an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, the problem is in the undefined command `\BIBand` to be used for multiple authors citation.

In the `informs2014.bst` file from [here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/pb-assets/Management-Science-template-1489419504967.zip) we can find

> ```
> FUNCTION {bbl.and}
> { "\protect\BIBand{}"}
> ```

and so the command `\BIBand` is in use. So it should be defined *somewhere*.

In the `Management-Science-template.tex` file (also from [here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/pb-assets/Management-Science-template-1489419504967.zip)) we can find

> ```
> % Natbib setup for author-year style
> \usepackage{natbib}
>  \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
>  \def\bibfont{\small}%
>  \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
>  \def\bibhang{24pt}%
>  \def\newblock{\ }%
>  \def\BIBand{and}%?
> ```

So, if you are not going to use their template, you have to copy the commands above to your preamble and everything should work and formated as expected.